# xpath how to get before the last element of <a>

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this html

```
<a class=pagination_klass></a>
<a class=pagination_klass></a>
<a class=pagination_klass></a>
<a class=pagination_klass></a>
<a class=pagination_klass>HERE</a>
<a class=pagination_klass></a>
```

I want to get the before last `<a>`

I tried this:

```
.//a[@class='pagination_klass' and position() = (last()-1)]/@href
```

but I got empty results.

help please.

#### note

I need to compare on the class name too

Comment: 1) that is invalid XML, as attributes must be contained within single or double quotes.  2) None of the `<a>` elements has an `href` attribute

Comment: @freefaller this is just to show you my problem, ofc this xml wouldn't work. but my questoin is completely different

Comment: Just get the entire list in one go and apply a simple list slice on it.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing that up. Always good to try and help somebody who gives you something "completely different" from what they're trying to fix. -1

Comment: @freefaller: "Give me the manual for the car. I need to fix the mower."

Comment: why there are guys downvote this question pelase? i have a problem, i tried to solve, i couldn't so I asked. what wrong with that?

Comment: @Nanashi "Give me the XPath for this XML. I need to match this other XML"... your point is??

Comment: @freefaller: If you didn't get it, that's exactly what he did. He asked for the manual of a car when he's trying to fix a mower. To OP, not really a bad question, but a very misleading one. As freefaller pointed out, there's not even an `href` in your example. Make the question *applicable* to your problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry @Nanashi - I thought it was a critism of my comment - it's been a long day!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi you got it almost correct. I removed **.** selector (current node selector) at beginning of XPath and I test it [here on Xpath tester](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=7a1c88f9-af15-46ec-80a8-1db79dea6f23-xpath#.U0LqpPl_shY%20Xpath%20tester). It works fine for me.

**//a[@class='pagination_klass' and position() = (last()-1)]/@href**

For

```
<html>
...
<a class='pagination_klass'></a>
<a class='pagination_klass'></a>
<a class='pagination_klass'></a>
<a class='pagination_klass'></a>
<a class='pagination_klass' href='LINK'>HERE</a>
<a class='pagination_klass'></a>
..
</html>
```

will be result attribute node href='LINK'.

Comment: you used the exact code that I gave, i told you it is not working

Comment: No, your Xpath starts with . which is current node selector. I only remove . and it works. Try it here http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=7a1c88f9-af15-46ec-80a8-1db79dea6f23-xpath#.U0LqpPl_shY only need to click on Evaluate XPath button on form.

Answer (score 4):

Your expression

```
.//a[@class='pagination_klass' and position() = (last()-1)]/@href
```

will select the second-to-last of all links but only if its class equals `pagination_klass`. If you want to find the second-to-last of all `pagination_klass` links, try:

```
.//a[@class='pagination_klass'][last()-1]/@href
```

Comment: I need the last href of all the a that has the mentioned class. so I have to use your first code, which is my code, but it is not working, also the second one is throwing an exception. please make sure that it doesn't need `/` ? between the brackets?